# python __name__ global variable gives different output than expected

Tags: python, global-variables, python-module, python-interactive, pythoninterpreter

I am trying to get a hands-on in python modules.

my code is,

```
#filename:module.py
def printname():
    print __name__

printname()
```

when I am executing the code with interpreter

```
python module.py
```

It gives output(i.e. module name as)

```
main
```

and when I import the module into another file and calling the module there it gives output as module name(expected).

```
module
```

according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files), It should give module name as output. Why is the variation in output??

Comment: Also according to the docs, no: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__name__#executing-modules-as-scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main script is **always** called `__main__`. This is entirely correct behaviour.

From the very same page you linked to,
 in the [preceding *Executing modules as scripts* section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts), you'll find:

> When you run a Python module with
>
> ```
> python fibo.py <arguments>
> ```
>
> the code in the module will be executed, just as if you imported it, but with the `__name__` set to `"__main__"`.

For everything you *import*, `__name__` will reflect the module name under which it was first available.

Also see the [*Interface options* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#interface-options):

> **`<script>`**
>
> [...]
>
> If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the directory containing that file is added to the start of sys.path, and the file is executed as the `__main__` module.

and the [*`__main__` Top-level script environment* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html):

> This module represents the (otherwise anonymous) scope in which the interpreter’s main program executes — commands read either from standard input, from a script file, or from an interactive prompt.